# Why is Bully algorithm in leader election considered synchronous?

Tags: distributed-systems, synchronization, consensus

The original paper of Bully algorithm [1] does not make any assumption of a synchronous processing. But I see few lectures explicitly call it suitable for synchronous processing. I am not sure why do we need to make an assumption of lock-step global iteration (aka synchronous processing)! First, I see that each ELECTION message can return the control immediately, and the receiving processor can then send an ACK when it finishes the evaluation of the specified criteria (e.g., receiving node wants to be a leader as well and has a higher id). My only suspicion is the requirements (mentioned as assumptions 7 and 9) that indicate the messages must be responded in the order of receiving and the channels should maintain the ordering.
Any insights would be much appreciated.

[1] Elections in a Distributed Computing System - Hector Garcia-Molina - 1982. See https://api.semanticscholar.org/CorpusID:15312445